# Spring Boot ManyToMany jackson recursion

Tags: spring, recursion, spring-boot, jackson

Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private int age;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Person> friends;
}
```

PersonController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController{
    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/findAll"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object findAll(){
        List<Person> people = personService.findAll();
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        response.put("msg", "王安生王person!");
        response.put("people", people);
        return response;
    }
}
```

database:
table person
[image: table person]

table person_friends
[image: table person_friends]

Why is the result of "/findAll" isinfinite loop?

Comment: At first its better to give the code as snippet only , along with the question, rather than photo. Its easy to understand the question here. Secondly, you are missing 2 images. Please edit and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

This link [Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) will help you to resovle your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,I made a mistake.The database is not suitable and the business logic is incorrect.